# Effects of high extracellular fluid calcium ion concentration - what's the reason behind it?

Tags: physiology, neurophysiology, action-potential

The Guyton and Hall Textbook of Medical Physiology, p. 76, says:

> For example, a high extracellular fluid calcium ion concentration decreases membrane permeability to sodium ions and simultaneously reduces excitability.

Why does this hold?

Naively, a high extracellular concentration of calcium ions should facilitate their flow through the calcium channels. Since the flow contributes to the action potential, the neurons should actually become hyperexcitable in the such a situation.

[This post](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11026/how-does-extracellular-potassium-ion-concentration-and-calcium-ion-concentration) suggests that a high extracellular concentration of calcium increases the extracellular potential, thus causing hyperpolarization of the cell. However, this doesn't make too much sense either because, then, a high extracellular concentration of Na+ would also decrease the excitability in a similar way.

Note: this question is related to [this one](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/11026/how-does-extracellular-potassium-ion-concentration-and-calcium-ion-concentration) but I'm rather expanding it.

Comment: Can you provide some more context on the quote? The part you've included starts "for example" so presumably there is more content there of what this is an example of...